# How do i send JSON data to a server in android using the OKHttp3 library

Tags: android

I am a bit confused here on the type of format that i should use to send my POST request to the server. i am getting a connection to the server and its giving me a 415 error. can someone help me on how to write the parameters for the JSON format that i should send. How do i write the JSON format. The code i had written is below:

```
   package googleplayservices.samples.android.com.whitney.shumba;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
   import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
   import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import java.io.IOException;

   import okhttp3.Call;
   import okhttp3.Callback;
   import okhttp3.FormBody;
   import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
   import okhttp3.Request;
   import okhttp3.RequestBody;
   import okhttp3.Response;

   public class Zesa extends AppCompatActivity {
   private TextInputEditText txtinputmeter,txtinputamount;
   private Button submit;
   private TextView json;
   private OkHttpClient client;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zesa);

    json = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonTV);
    txtinputmeter = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_input_meter);
    txtinputamount = (TextInputEditText) 
   findViewById(R.id.txt_input_amount);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Submit();
        }
    });
    client = new OkHttpClient();
   }
    private void Submit() {
    //Okhttp3 request to engine
       FormBody.Builder formBuilder = new FormBody.Builder()
             .add({"txtinputmeter", :"00000000000",
                   "txtinputamount" : "0.00"
                   })
     formBuilder.add("txtinputamount", "0.00");
     RequestBody formBody = formBuilder.build();

    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://52.8.97.52/zesa")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    json.setText("Failure !");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) {
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   try {
                       json.setText(response.body().string());
                   }catch (IOException ioe){
                       json.setText("Error during execution");
                   }
               }
           });
        }
      });

     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

415 means your payload is not in proper format. try replacing the line

```
    .add({"txtinputmeter", :"00000000000",
               "txtinputamount" : "0.00"
               });
```

with

```
      .add("txtinputmeter","00000000000");
```